# Dynamicaly obtain json array from json object

Tags: android, json

I am trying to obtain a JSON Array from a JSON object on the android platform. The thing is you never know what the name could be for the name value pair that corresponds to any of the arrays orrr the size or number of arrays. I believe you can attempt to do this by using a hash of some sort? Don't really know how to aprroach this issue. Any help, tips, and links are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each key value pair and see which is an Array. If you can have multiple Arrays, you need something to uniquely identify this is the Array you are looking for. Maybe number of items in the Array or that it has some unique key value pairs. Of course, you can also try to add a key value pair that uniquely identifies itself to that Array, such as id => "this is my array", and look for to see if that key value pair exists.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the name of the value pair at run time? Then use the value to get the array?